# Fill Enumerable Inside Enumerable in .NET 5

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ienumerable, enumeration

I have a "Panel" model that has multiple "Panel Pages". I would like to get a list of all panels, and fill each panel with its respective "Panel Pages".

Here is my code currently (that works):

```
public IEnumerable<DynamicCustomPanel> GetCustomPanels()
{
    var customPanels = _customPanelService.GetDynamicCustomPanels();
    var dynamicCustomPanels = customPanels.ToList();

    foreach (var customPanel in dynamicCustomPanels.ToList())
    {
        var customPanelPages = _customPanelPageService.GetCustomPanelPages(customPanel.PanelGUID.ToString());
        customPanel.CustomPanelPages = customPanelPages;
    }

    return dynamicCustomPanels;
}
```

How do I do this in an minimal amount of lines?

Comment: `How do I do this in an minimal amount of lines?` are there issues, perhaps maintenance and or performance?

Comment: Get rid of those extra `ToList()` calls. They eat up memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public IEnumerable<DynamicCustomPanel> GetCustomPanels()
{
    return _customPanelService.GetDynamicCustomPanels().Select(p => {
         p.CustomPanelPages = _customPanelPageService.GetCustomPanelPages(p.PanelGUID.ToString());
         return p;
     });
}
```

That's technically 3 statements (two returns and an assignment) and one block, though it's kind of an abuse of the `Select()` method. I might write it like this instead:

```
public IEnumerable<DynamicCustomPanel> GetCustomPanels()
{
    foreach(var p in _customPanelService.GetDynamicCustomPanels())
    {
        p.CustomPanelPages = _customPanelPageService.GetCustomPanelPages(p.PanelGUID.ToString());
        yield return p;
    }
}
```

Which is... also 3 statements (counting `foreach`) and one block, just spaced different to use one more line of text.